# Aria2 - Download eventually stops while using --lowest-speed-limit

Tags: aria2

While using --lowest-speed-limit option to set up minimal speed, I was hoping for new connections to be created when a slow one gets closed. Unfortunatelly, when a connection is dropping, no new is created.

Is it possible to configure re-creation of dropped connections?

My current command:

```
aria2c http://file
--continue=true
--lowest-speed-limit=100K 
--always-resume=true 
-j 16 
-x 16
```